# Getting IP address and Port from UDP Packet

Tags: networking, udp, ip, port, netcat

I have a server set-up with netcat:

```
nc -l 4444 -u
```

And a client:

```
nc 127.0.0.1 4444 -u
```

I am using localhost because they are both on my computer, but if the client moves to another computer, is there a way for netcat to tell me the ip address and port number of the client?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `-v` or `-vv` for verbose logging, that will tell you client IP and port.

Comment: when I add `-v` to it but that does not seem to be working, I do not know if this matter but I am running it on a mac, I had to change localhost to 127.0.0.1 because localhost has stopped working altogether.

Comment: Yes, BSD variant does not tell you that. Try GNU netcat (http://netcat.sourceforge.net) if you are so inclined.

Comment: same problem in windows if using Cygwin...
solved using nc.exe from v1.12 NT http://eternallybored.org/misc/netcat/